# HTML AJAX live updating PHP varible with count up animation using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to making live variable which updates every second which works but when I add count function there then there I can see 0 for 1 second and after that variable shows without animation. My goal is to make variable which at first load page counts from 0 to "var. value" for example **18** and if variable change for example to **20**, then there will be count ani. from **18** to **20**. I don't actually know how I can achieve it because I can't get previous variable because it's store in **global_users.php**

**index.php**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#players").load("global_users.php")

    setInterval(function () {
        $("#players").load("global_users.php")
    }, 1000);
});
</script>

<span class="Count" id="players"></span>

<script>
    $('.Count').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**global_users.php**

```
<?php
include("php/server.php");
echo $total_online = $serverInfo['Players'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies in the usage of [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) method, which can be useful, but not for this case. Under the hood of `.load()` is [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) which allows you to make a request to the server with jQuery. Use it to get access to the player count value that the server returns with each request.

Split up the code in two functions, one for getting the player count and one for updating the player count with an animation. Whenever the first function has downloaded a new count and that count is different from the one that you already have, call the second function to update and animate.

```
<span class="count" id="players"></span>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Set starting count.
  let count = 0;
  const $players = $('#players');

  /**
   * Updates the player count with an animation and
   * saves the new player count.
   */
  function updatePlayerCount(newCount) {
    $({ 
      counter: count // Starting value, which is the last known count value.
    }).animate({ 
      counter: newCount // Value to animate to, which is the new count value.
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function() {
        $players.text(Math.ceil(this.counter));
      },
      complete: function() {
        count = newCount; // Update the count value after the animation to compare it later again.
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Gets the count value from the server and 
   * passes it to the updatePlayerCount function
   * if the count has been changed.
   */
  function getPlayerCount() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'global_users.php',
      method: 'GET'
    }).done(function(newCount) {
      newCount = Number(newCount); // Makes sure that the value is a number.
      if (count !== newCount) { 
        updatePlayerCount(newCount); // newCount is a different value than count, so updatePlayerCount is called.
      }
    });
  }

  // Execute getPlayerCount every 5 seconds.
  setInterval(getPlayerCount, 5000);

});
```

Comment: I would have question, why updatePlayerCount gets called twice when is page refreshed?

Comment: `$.ajax()` can take a little while to complete. The animation takes a second to complete before the count is updated. Those two can overlap which causes `updatePlayerCount` to be called again before the animation is complete and the count value updated. So increasing the interval to, let's say 5 seconds, would solve that.

Comment: It does, thanks for helping me and adding these comments in code.